# How to get checked checkboxes and corresponding information using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have some Checkboxes with captions on a page, I want to get all checked the checkboxes and corresponds information of that checkbox using jQuery?

Ultimately, I want to submit a form with everything the user has selected. But since the form does not know, I need to get the information when the user clicks on the button that opens form.

Thanks!

```
<section id="myoptions">

<label for="123">
<div class="thisineed">Want this text</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="123"></div>
<div class="thisaswell">This one I want as well</div>
</label>

<label for="124">
<div class="thisineed">Want this text</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="124"></div>
<div class="thisaswell">This one I want as well</div>
</label>

</section>
```

Comment: In what format do you want all that information? It looks like you are wanting the class and content of every div within the input's parent label? What are you planning to do with this? Also it looks like those who answered didn't read the question really - so far.

Comment: Can you explain the second phrase better? about want you want to do after?

Comment: Yes. Apologies if it was not clear. Essentially, I have a form that the user can open if they click on a button. When the click happens, I want to get the information on what was checked and store it maybe in a hidden textarea for it to be submitted once the form loads and the user submits it. The form opens in a layer using fancybox. The reason I need to somehow get what the user has checked is that the checkboxes are not part of the actual form.

Comment: Great, and what information, assuming that both of those checkboxes are checked, do you want to have returned/stored in the hidden input or variable or whatever?

Comment: the information in the divs right before and after the checkbox. See code example in my quesiton. Though if I know how to get the checkboxes, I should be able to get the corresponding divs without further assistance.

Comment: There's HTML, which is great, but I still don't see exactly what you want to store. Is it the `id` and the `value` *as well as* the text in the surrounding elements, or *just* the surrounding text? If you show the expected/desired output it makes answering your question so very much easier. Also if you prefix my name with an `@` (so `@David`/`@DavidThomas` etc) I'll be notified of your response.

Comment: @user2515479, check the demo I just added, is that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this to reach the checked checkboxes:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
    console.log(this); 
});
```

Here is a example to you. It's a bit unclear what you are looking for but check this:

```
$('#get_form').click(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        console.log(my_form);
        var somevalue = $(this).parent().next('.thisaswell').text();
        console.log(somevalue);
        $('#my_form').append('<input type="hidden" value="'+somevalue+'" />')
    });
});
```

And this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mSHwH/)** produces hidden inputs in a form I added as example with the text from the div after..

Comment: I was under the impression that [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returned a Boolean (`true`/`false`) rather than a jQuery object. I *think* you're thinking of using `filter()`, given the selector you're passing in?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#getOptions').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var opts = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function () {
        return this.checked;
    }).map(function () {
        var p = $(this).closest('div');
        return [p.prev().text(), p.next().text()];
    }).get(),
        hidden = $('<input />', {
            'type': 'hidden'
        });
    $.each(opts, function (i, v) {
        hidden.clone().val(v).appendTo('form');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vuDdz/2/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector to get checkboxes and [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) filter to get the checked checkboxes then use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to fetch the required data from those checkboxes

```
var array = $('#myoptions input').filter(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){
    return { id: this.id, value: this.value}
}).get()
```

Comment: Please check the edit; though I'm *pretty* sure that `mao()` isn't a jQuery method... ;)

Comment: @DavidThomas it was a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var checkboxvalue='';
$('#myoptions input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    var this_input=$(this);
    if(this_input.is(':checked')){
    checkboxvalue += this_input.attr('value')    ;
   }

})
alert(checkboxvalue)
```